# Zero-mean and unit variance image batch

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on implementing a convolutional neural network for classifying medical images and I am trying to zero-mean and unit variance my input data (RGB images) before feeding it to my network.
My data is of shape [num_images, image_width, image_height, image_channels]

I'm using numpy:

```
mean_val = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
std_val = np.std(X_train, axis=0)
normalized_images = (X_train-mean_val)/std_val
```

However the images have different shapes therefore I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/TristanSaunders/Desktop/IndividualProject/Amazon_Test.py", line 
162, in <module>
mean_val = np.mean(lab_images, axis=0)
File "/Users/TristanSaunders/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2909, in mean
out=out, **kwargs)
File "/Users/TristanSaunders/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 70, in _mean
ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (767,1022,3) 
(488,744,3)
```

This only works when the images have the same shape. This is fine because I reshape the images to 224x224x3 before feeding them to the network but to get the images to have the same shape I need to resize and then pad them in order to keep the aspect ratio of the image. But doing zero-mean and unit variance on padded images causes the abundance of zero-valued pixels (padding) to skew the mean-value.

Therefore I am trying to zero-mean and unit variance my images before reshaping them and I was wondering if there's a solution to do so when the images have different shapes?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the shape of X_train?

Comment: Before resizing the images X_train has shape (num_images,).
After resizing all images to 224x224x3, X_train has shape (num_images, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: have you tried leaving axis=0 out?

Comment: Gives the same error I put in my question.

Comment: You could pad with `nan` use `nanmean` and `nanstd` and afterwards apply `np.nan_to_num` which replaces nan with 0.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, Thanks! I think your solution works, but because it ignores the NaNs it means that some images, even when resized, will have more non-NaN pixels than others. Should I not account for these when calculating the mean and std? As "warped" suggested in his answer below.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `nanmean` and `nanstd` should do the correct normalization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that X_train is a list. You can call np.mean() on it if all elements of the list have the same shape. 
If the shapes are different, you can do

```
mean_val = np.mean([np.mean(a) for a in X_train])
```

This should compute, but images with small pixel numbers would be over-represented.

So, to compensate, you could do

```
total_pixels = np.sum([a.flatten().shape for a in X_train])
mean_val = np.sum([a.flatten().shape * np.mean(a) for a in X_train]) / total_pixels
```